# Python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' on a global variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, edgedriver

I don't understand why I cannot set a global variable `driver` in Selenium

I get this error in the `Load()` function on `driver`

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
  File "D:\Code\edge_script.py", line xx, in load
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Code\edge_script.py", line xx, in main
    load()
  File "D:\Code\edge_script.py", line xx, in <module>
    main()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pathlib import Path
import time
import subprocess
import re

from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

#global variables
driver = None
    
def init():
    subprocess.run("taskkill /f /im msedge.exe")

    edge_options = EdgeOptions()
    edge_options.use_chromium = True    

    #Here you set the path of the profile ending with User Data not the profile folder
    path  = "user-data-dir="+str(Path.home())+"\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data"
    print(path)
    edge_options.add_argument(path); 

    #Here you specify the actual profile folder    
    edge_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    edge_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 

    edge_options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
    driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "D:\\msedgedriver.exe")

def load():
    # navigate to the website
    driver.get("https://www.google.com") #<<<ERROR HERE

    # wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(5)

def close():
    # close the driver
    driver.quit()

def main():

    init()
    load()
    close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If ```driver``` is a global variable, aren't you supposed to include the ```global driver``` statement in your ```load()``` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you have defined `driver` as a global variable and it's set to `None`.

In `init()`, you assigning an instance of the Edge driver to `driver` but since you haven't declared `driver` as `global`, python is just assigning it to a local variable named `driver` which is destroyed as soon as you leave `init()`.

Add a `global` declaration inside `init()` to fix this issue and you don't need it in `load()` or elsewhere because you're only *reading* `driver` not assigning to it.

Your final code should be

```
#global variables
driver = None
    
def init():
    global driver # <<<<<< add this here
    subprocess.run("taskkill /f /im msedge.exe")

    edge_options = EdgeOptions()
    edge_options.use_chromium = True    

    #Here you set the path of the profile ending with User Data not the profile folder
    path  = "user-data-dir="+str(Path.home())+"\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data"
    print(path)
    edge_options.add_argument(path); 

    #Here you specify the actual profile folder    
    edge_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    edge_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
    edge_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 

    edge_options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
    driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = "D:\\msedgedriver.exe")

def load():
    # navigate to the website
    driver.get("https://www.google.com") #<<<ERROR HERE

    # wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(5)

def close():
    # close the driver
    driver.quit()

def main():

    init()
    load()
    close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -3):

Need to declare global variable in python function unlike other languages

```
def load():
    global driver
    # navigate to the website
    driver.get("https://www.google.com") 

    # wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: ditto within the close() function

Comment: **no**, this is all wrong. @Mich this is not the use case for `global`. You only need it when *setting* the variable, not reading it. Thus, adding this under `init()` function instead, should fix the issue.